# Variable that stores multiple data?

Tags: javascript

When i look at others code (because im curious how they do things) i common stumble across a specific var that catches my eye for example:

```
var data = {
  names = 0;
  charMove = 0;
  hunger = 100;
  thirst = 100;
}
```

I want to understand this for later when it could be useful in some of *my* code. I have a moderate understanding on javascript code and love to learn as much as i can so if you have anything please do tell!

Comment: What you've got here is the foundation of JavaScript programming; it will be covered thoroughly in any JavaScript course. I recommend finding any JavaScript course and getting through the first 20% to understand this construct.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: I don't people should be answering this question by explaining but rather by recommending a good tutorial like [this one](http://eloquentjavascript.net/)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir No, that’s what comments are for. Answers are exactly for explaining further.

Comment: @Xufox agree but if the explanation is simpler. This kind of questions requires a lot of explaining (thus not suitable for answers on SO). It'll be better if someone recommend a tutorial like I said where he can learn everything surrounding that topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are probably talking about are Objects (although they are defined a little bit different).

They basically are just a Map or Dictionary that maps keys to values and are defined as follows:

```
var obj = {
  key: "value",
  key2: true,
  key3: function() {}
}
```

Where the right side can be pretty much everything including other objects.

values can be accessed (read and write) by using `obj.key` or `obj["key"]`

You can read up more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Answer (score 1):

That is an object. There are *multiple* ways to create objects in JavaScript.

```
// An object.
    var someObject = new Object();


// An object literal (the preferred way of creating objects).
    var anotherObject = {};
```

They’re doing the *exact* same thing, but object literals are quicker to write. It’s also good to use white-space (tabs, and spaces) for neatness and readability.

Moreover, objects are merely **collections of name/value pairs**. In example:

```
var person = {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname:  'Doe'
};
```

'Person' is the object, and it has some properties. 'firstname' and 'lastname' are the **keys**, while 'John' and 'Doe' are the **values**. Values can also be other collections of name/value pairs. For example:

```
var person = {
        firstname: 'John',
        lastname:  'Doe',
        address: {
          street: '111 Main St.',
          city: 'New York',
          state: 'NY'
        }
    };
```

A property of an object could be a primitive type (a boolean, string, number, etc.) or it could be another object — a child object *so-to-speak*. An object, along with its properties, can also contain **methods** which are nothing more than functions. However, we use the term 'method' when referring to a function that lives *within* an object.

Example of an object literal containing a method as one of its properties (which is just a function inside an object):

```
var person = {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname:  'Doe'

    method: function(parameters) {
    // do something;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
var player = {
  "level" : 1,
  "x" : 0,
  "y" : 0,
  "score" : 0,
}
```

The above is what it called Javascript object, a key-value representation...

Comment: Its actually just an object. While JSON is built the same, keys in JSON have to be put in qotations and some values are not supported (like functions). JSON is also more or less a serialisazion / text-representation of objects used to communicate between processes

Comment: It’s a JavaScript object. [There's no such thing as a “JSON Object”](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: @VeeMandke You didn’t really make it better… this still isn’t a JSON object, because JSON objects don’t exist. We call this a JavaScript object. The quotations are unnecessary here.

Answer (score -2):

I dont use javascript but it looks like a type or struct.  each member field can be accessed on its own.

The entire struct can be initialised at once such as

```
var player = {
  level = 1,
  x = 0,
  y = 0,
  score = 0
}
```

then the member felds can be modified individualy, such as

```
player.score = player.score + 100;
```

A struct make it much easier to pass multiple data into functions rather than having to pass separate variables.

Comment: only if you put `,` (commas) instead of `;` (semi-collons) as the separator.